# Kannel :: How can I filter incoming traffic

Tags: kannel

I use Kannel as SMS gateway - It works fine for me. I am connnected one operator and I provide SMPP COnnections to my clients. All works fine.
But now I need to filter the traffic based on the recipient number ie I need to be able to set a REGEX for the receipient and reject the SMS if it's supposed to be sent to those recipients.
Is this possible in Kannel? Any idea of how this can be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Core group configuration](https://kannel.org/download/1.4.5/userguide-1.4.5/userguide.html#AEN482) (i.e. bearerbox configuration) has parameters for `white-list-receiver-regex` and `black-list-receiver-regex`, those should do what you're looking for. That is, however, a system-wide setting, not a per-SMSC setting so it applies to all numbers through all SMSC connections.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. I don't know why I have seen that in the guide initially but never thought is was the solution. Anyway, thanks a lot!
Now I think I would be perfectly happy if I could set that restriction per client, so Client A could have a different restriction and Client B.